# How to list files in shortcut folder in GDrive v3

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api, gdrive

I am trying to use the GDrive API v3 to list all files and folders in a shortcut folder.

When using the API I am able to list all files using the following request:

```
curl \
  'https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?q=%27root%27%20in%20parents&supportsAllDrives=true&supportsTeamDrives=true&key=[YOUR_API_KEY]' \
  --header 'Authorization: Bearer [YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN]' \
  --header 'Accept: application/json' \
  --compressed
```

Which returns something like:

```
{
    "kind": "drive#file",
    "id": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "name": "Name of file here",
    "mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.shortcut"
}
```

When I take that id, and use it in the same request above, which works for `"mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.folder"`. I get an empty payload:

```
{
 "kind": "drive#fileList",
 "incompleteSearch": false,
 "files": []
}
```

Am I using the wrong endpoint? Is there something else I need to add to the API request?

Comment: mimetype for a folder is application/vnd.google-apps.folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### The shortcut item in your Drive has an attribute with the id of the actual folder.

If for example, you have only one shortcut to a folder in your Drive when you make the request you will get **two results** when listing all files in root.

1. one with mime type "shortcut" - which is the shortcut.
2. one with mime type "folder" - seems that the API lists this anyway.

If for any reason you only get the shortcut, you can get the details of the shortcut:

#### Request

```
curl \
  'https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/[YOUR_SHORTCUT_ID]?fields=*&key=[YOUR_API_KEY]' \
  --header 'Authorization: Bearer [YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN]' \
  --header 'Accept: application/json' \
  --compressed
```

#### Response

(I have removed most of the fields from the response)

```json
{
 "kind": "drive#file",
 "id": "[YOUR_SHORTCUT_ID]",
 "name": "[YOUR_SHORTCUT_NAME]",
 "mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.shortcut",
 "starred": false,
 "trashed": false,
 "shortcutDetails": {
  "targetId": "[THE_ACTUAL_FOLDER_ID]",
  "targetMimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.folder"
 }
}
```

Within `shortcutDetails` is the `targetId`.

After which, you can write your original request with the proper `"ID" in parents`.

#### Reference

- [Create a shortcut with Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/shortcuts)

Comment: I thought I tried this and it didn't work. I tried it again and BOOM all good. Is there a way to bring back just the `shortcutDetails` vs the whole payload as it is large. `fields=*` is there a way to bring back few fields? I need the same fields as what you get when you exclude this param plus just the `shortcutDetails`. Is this possible?

Comment: Yes its possible, see [this](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/fields-parameter).

Answer (score 0):

The shortcut is not synonymous with the directory it points to. You will need to make two requests, one to get the target ID ("targetId") from the shortcut and then a second call to find files with `targetId in parents`.